# Is it possible to change os.path.join root path?

Tags: python, path, os.path

I want to get absolute paths based on a user-defined path, so that when I do `os.path.join('whatever', '/file')` it returns `USERPATH/file'`.

Right now it returns `/file` (assuming it's an absolute path)

Is there a way of telling os.path.join which should be the root path? (so that when it considers something an absolute path, it prepends this root path)

What I want to do:

```
> # Do something to set the root path to USERPATH

> os.path.join('folder','file')
folder/file
> os.path.join('folder','/file')
USERPATH/file
> os.path.join('/folder','file')
USERPATH/folder/file
> os.path.join('/folder','/file')
USERPATH/file
```

Comment: Downvotes need not be explained. However, if you hover over a downvote arrow, you get a tooltip that says: "this question does not show any research effort, it is unclear **or** not useful".

Answer (score 1):

Technically there are 2 ways: monkeypatch the `os.path` module, or use the [`chroot`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chroot.2.html) system call. Unfortunately this will also change all the other path handling on Python, and also make your program probably not function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prepend based on something being an absolute path check first then concat whatever you want:

```
import os
f = os.path.join('whatever', '/file')
if os.path.isabs(f):
    pth = "USERPATH/{}".format(f)
```

Comment: The concat thing is more or less what I'm doing right now, but I wanted to know whether there was a built-in (aka safer) way of doing it

Comment: A path is either an abspath or not, how were you testing if the path was an absolute  path? Also  join only takes a path or *paths and returns a string so there is no method that will test if it is an absolute path you can call on join

Comment: I don't really get your point, but os.path.join has a special case for abspaths: `If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component.`

And I wanted to know if there's a built-in way of modifying what it will result as an abspath

Comment: @fawques, yes so what is the problem? Either compare after joining to the original string  or use isabspath. which does exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: Ok, so, answering my question: "no, there isn't a way of doing that". Thanks

Comment: No there is no way to do it using `os.path.join`  as I said in an earlier comment, it takes a path as an argument and returns a string.